# Is HD1 Galaxy a potential Big Bang theory killer?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, space-expansion, big-bang, galaxies

I have heard some first explanations of why the farthest ever galaxy discovered about 13.27 Bly away the [HD1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HD1_(galaxy)) appears so UV active and about the population III stars inside this galaxy made only from ingredients provided directly by the big bang essentially only hydrogen and helium therefore with larger UV emissions as normal or a gigantic very energetic Black Hole 100 million times the mass of the sun which however cannot be explained how such a massive BH could be formed roughly only 330 million years after the Big Bang?

This is all very fascinating and I hope the new Webb space telescope will give the answers.

But I don't understand how the scientists resolved from the redshift the distance of HD1?

If HD1 light is indeed as claimed abnormal in UV content (very high UV) would that not mess up the whole redshift measurement and calculations,  making HD1 deceivingly appear closer to us from what it really is thus this galaxy could be actually even more far away?

How we compensated the redshift distance measurement for the abnormal UV content?

Also I have heard that high content in dust inside a galaxy can also give a false redshift distance reading? Making the galaxy appear more far away than it really is?

Comment: Why would the UV mess up the redshift measurement?

Comment: @PM2Ring Would that not shift the whole spectrum of the galaxy towards the blue making the galaxy appear less redshifted?

Comment: That doesn't matter. We aren't looking at a single colour. We're looking at a pattern of lines, like in the top diagram here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift We measure how much the whole pattern is shifted, relative to where those lines are when we look at the spectrum of those elements in the lab.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks that was helpful. So you compare how much more deeper red the distant galaxy contains compared to our sun? But could this not also be because of dust?

Answer (score 4):

When interpreting the spectrum of a far away galaxy the original spectrum is reconstructed.

For comparison first a simpler case:
Back when astronomers first took spectrum measurements of light from our own Sun there was negligable frequency shift as compared to spectral measurements in labs on Earth. This allowed the astronomers to identify two things: the chemical composition of the Sun surface, and the temperature of the Sun surface.

Chemical elements have a spectrum of emission/absorption lines. At relatively low temperature the recorded spectrum is dominated by comparitively low energy transitions. With higher temperature the high energy transitions comprise a higher proportion of the total spectrum.

Chemists and physicists could do the experiments in Earth labs to see to what temperature an element must be heated so that it produces the same distribution of spectral lines as the observations of Sun spectral lines.

As to distant galaxies: the redshift shifts all of the lines in the same proportion, leaving the distribution intact. The signatures of various chemical elements can still be identified. This allows the astronomers to infer the original energies. The high UV content that is mentioned refers to the *reconstructed* composition, not the raw spectrum as measured by the spectrum measurment device of the observing telescope.